# variable cannot be echo out when viewing

Tags: php

I wanted to echo out the description from the database.
however, when I view it, it couldn't be loaded .
I wonder why, is it because the html is in textarea format, thus it cannot be echo out?
because when I echo out others variable, it can be echo out. those are in text field format

this is my code

php code

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["manager"])){
    header("location: admin_login.php");
    exit();
}
//check that manager session is in database
$managerID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["id"]);
    $manager = preg_replace('#[^A_Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["manager"]);
    $password = preg_replace('#[^A_Za-z0-9]#i','',$_SESSION["password"]);


    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id = '$managerID' AND username='$manager' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1");

//make sure person exist in database
$existCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($existCount == 0) {
    echo " Your login session data is not on record in the database";
exit();
}
?>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['description'])){

    $pid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['thisID']);
    $product_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);
    $product_price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_price']);
    $category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
    $subcategory = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subcategory']);
    $product_description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description']);
    $product_package = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product_package']);


$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE supermarket SET category='$category', subcategory='$category',name='$product_name', description='$product_description',packaging='$product_package', price='$product_price' WHERE id='$pid'");


if($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'] != "") {
    //place image in the folder
$newname = "$product_description.jpg";
//place image in the folder
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'],"images/$newname");
}
    header("location: inventorylist.php"); 
    exit();



}

?>

<?php 
//gather this product full info
if(isset($_GET['pid'])){
    $targetID = $_GET['pid'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM supermarket WHERE id = '$targetID' LIMIT 1");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);//count output amount
if($productCount > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $product_description = $row["description"];
        $product_name = $row["name"];
        $category = $row["category"];
        $subcategory = $row["subcategory"];
        $product_price = $row["price"];
        $product_package = $row["packaging"];




    }

}
else{
    $product_list = "Sorry, it don't exist";
    exit();
}

}

?>
```

html code for php

```
<textarea name="description" id="description" value="<?php echo $product_description ?>" cols="64" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
 <textarea name="description" id="description"  cols="64" rows="5"><?php echo $product_description ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

`textarea` has no `value` attribute.
It should be: `<textarea><?=$var?></textarea>`